# Having an issue with Polymer not recognizing a class I make in the imported file

Tags: javascript, polymer

fairly new to Polymer -- I'm having an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I have this bit of javascript code at the end of the file I am importing for my custom polymer element:

```
Polymer('metafaq-name', {

     ready: function (){
            var subby = document.querySelector('.classname');
            console.log(subby);

            subby.onclick = function () {
            console.log('clicky');
            }
          }
      });
```

and despite me being relatively new to javascript I'm pretty sure there's no (major) errors because it works on any class that's in the main html file, just not on the classes IN the custom polymer element html file where I create it.

Any ideas? I can't seem to get it to recognize any class or ID that's in the file. My thoughts have been that there might be an issue with how the custom element is actually getting imported, like maybe it's adding the script before the rest of the element, but I thought by adding a 'ready' it would fix this issue, so now I'm out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Shan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node resides in [shadow DOM](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html) (in template, if you will), so you should do a query on `shadowRoot`.
Like this:

`this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.className')`

If you just want to assign a click handler, you could just say so in in your tag as an [on-click](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html) - (*check under 'Declarative event mapping'*) - attribute.

For example:

```
<button on-click="{{hiThere}}">
```

And then:

```
Polymer('your-element)', {
  hiThere: function() { 
    alert('hi') 
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about shadowRoot at all. Works perfectly! Thank you so much :-) And yeah the onClick was mostly just for testing. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't mind if I suggest to first read a bit about polymer, go through some of the videos on `googledevelopers` yt channel as well as to check out some really neat examples on polymer website. It's a suggested (and optimal) path to learning it. If you use IRC, come by on #polymer @ irc@freenode.net . Google engineers are there :)

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I've been reading through the Polymer website but I'm kind of new to javascript so it's been hard to understand a lot of it. I'll check out the IRC channel and the YT vids. Thanks :-)